# Are there pros & cons in rendering three.js on <canvas> instead of <div>?

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas, renderer

I've seen in three.js examples using:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: document.querySelector( 'canvas' ) } );
```

which refers to a `<canvas></canvas>` element.

That is in contrast to:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var container = getelementbyid("container"):
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

which refers to a `<div></div>` element.

In both cases WebGLRenderer is used, and canvas can also be styled, so is it exactly the same, or are there any pros and cons, like devices' support, performance and limitations -why one should chose one vs the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is intended for users who want to explicitly pass in a custom canvas element. If you don't do this, `WebGLRenderer` will create an internal canvas in its constructor (see [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/39731e208f349c733b7faa3ad572746504a0f12d/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L62)).

In both cases `renderer.domElement` represents the drawing surface and is just a reference to a canvas element. `container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );` is necessary to append the internal canvas to the DOM. But you don't necessarily have to use a container element for this. `document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement )` is sufficient in most cases.

Comment: "But you don't necessarily have to use a container element for this. document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement ) is sufficient in most cases."
Thanks, that's good to know too.